# Add percentage (%) to a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to add the percentage (df$Freq) at the end (right side) of each horizontal bar?

```
City <- c("Rome", "Paris", "Madrid", "London", "Berlin", "Ottawa")
N <- c(230, 752, 957, 473, 178, 389)
Freq <- round(proportions(N) * 100, 2)
df <- data.frame(City, N, Freq)

plt <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(N, fct_relevel(City,
                              "Berlin",
                              "Rome",
                              "Ottawa",
                              "London",
                              "Paris",
                              "Madrid",
                              )), 
               fill = "grey75", 
           width = 0.6) + 
  xlab("Total") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000),
                     breaks = seq(0, 900, by = 250)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  labs(title = "Graph - Example")

plt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option: move the x and y arguments to the call to `ggplot`. Then use a call to `geom_text` to generate the label with `hjust` to align to the right of the bars.
I suspect this question is a duplicate.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(df, aes(N, fct_relevel(City, "Berlin",
                                   "Rome",
                                   "Ottawa",
                                   "London",
                                   "Paris",
                                   "Madrid"))) +
  geom_col(fill = "grey75",
           width = 0.6) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Freq, "%")), hjust = -0.1)+
  xlab("Total") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000),
                     breaks = seq(0, 900, by = 250)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  labs(title = "Graph - Example")
```

A variation on this approach which does more of the work in `ggplot`.
Using `fct_reorder` is probably a safer way to order the city names.
Use `after_stat` derive the percentage frequency label to save adding a variable to the original data frame. Depending on your use case this may or may not be useful.

```
ggplot(df, aes(N, fct_reorder(City, N))) +
  geom_col(fill = "grey75",
           width = 0.6) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(paste0(round(proportions(N) * 100, 2), "%")) ), hjust = -0.1)+
  xlab("Total") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000),
                     breaks = seq(0, 900, by = 250)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  labs(title = "Graph - Example")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: No problems, have added some alternative approaches, please tick accept if this answers your question.